# Python ES client deleting the doces while inserting bulk data with bulk helper

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, analytics

```
    jsondata = f.read()
    dataList = json.loads(jsondata)
    projectName = dataList['query']['project']
    reportStartTime = dataList['query']['startTime']
    reportEndTime = dataList['query']['endTime']
    allEventList = dataList['sessionEvents']

    '''We need a Type for each data so it will be
     like startTime:endTime'''
     flag = False
     count = 0
     esbulkData = []
     for event in allEventList:
         ls = event["l"]
         del event["l"]
         for l in ls:
    llist = []
    eventList = []
    llist.append(l)
    event["l"] = llist
    eventList.append(event)
    flurryData = { "project": projectName, "startTime": reportStartTime, "endTime": reportEndTime, "sessionEvents": eventList }
    #{
    #      "_index": "tickets-index",
    #      "_type": "tickets",
    #      "_id": j,
    #      "_source": {
    #          "any":"data" + str(j),
    #          "timestamp": datetime.now()}
    #  }
    esData = {"_index": "fl_ios_prod_feb_bulk", "_type": "flurryRawSchema", "_id": count, "_source": flurryData}
    esbulkData.append(esData)
    es = Elasticsearch([ES_URL])
    res = helpers.bulk(es, esbulkData)
    if (res):
       print("Passed")

    else:
       print("Failed")
```

In above code, everything works just fine but doc_count don't go more than 500 while checking on "Sense". It seems to have deleted some docs.

Please help. I am having those nights

Answer (score 0):

Okay So I forget to increase the count and that what was issue.